# Ag Grid - React- Change the Grouped row colour Based on group data status -

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to change the colour of the group row based on the group data status.

[Ag Grid sample Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PwGj.png)

[Detailed problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N9kq.png)

As per the above image , I want to change the background colour of 2008, if all below rows of swimming. Can somebody please help me on this. Help highly appreciated.

Ag Grid - React

Comment: Wellcome, @Ganesh Koilada! You can embedd the image directly in your question. And if possible, I suggest you to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the "cellStyle" attributes in the columnDefs props and handle the color directly there depending on the data.

```js
var columnDef = [{
  // Other columns
  ...
  {
    headerName: "Year",
    field: "year",
    cellStyle: function(params) {
      // adjust params.node.data.year depending on the of your attribute
      const year = params.node.data.year;
      
      // Default value
      let background = "#333";
      
      if (year === 2008) {
        background = "#f60"
      } 
      
      return background;
    }
  },
  // Other columns
  ...
];
```

If you could do a stackblitz of you code, it would be easier for us to help you.

Good coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question is need to highlight the grouped row 2008 not the 2008 which in the row data. i.e when I click the group by Year the group by row need to be styled.

Comment: @GaneshKoilada Could you update your question with the code of your problem please?

Comment: @@jbergeron  I tried cellStyle and rowStyle but those are not applicable for grouped row , I have attached one more image. Can you please check that .